# How do I perform a binarysearch on one field of a List that is another class?

Tags: java, class, methods

I am comparing inputted dates to a list of holidays.

The holiday objects consist of a string with the name and a jodatime Datetime.

In the Holidays class, I have:

```
public static List<Holiday> getAllHolidays() {
    return allHolidays;
}
```

In my main class, I have:

```
public static boolean isHoliday(List<Holiday> holidayList, DateTime date) {
    if(Collections.binarySearch(holidayList.date, date)) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
```

This is where the problem is as I get that "date cannot be resolved or is not a field"

The goal is to be able to access the isHoliday method as follows:

```
isHoliday(Holidays.getAllHolidays(), hearingDate)
```

I am able to get this to work with a for loop search but I am trying to get this to work with a binary search since it is a sorted list.

Comment: I would define a `Comparator<Holiday>` that only uses the `date` field for its ordering. Not sure if redefining `equals()` is needed (my gut tells me that it is not).

Comment: SJuan76, that is the correct answer. Why don't you make it an answer so I can give you internet points?

Answer (score 0):

What is this `holidayList.date` ? (This is `List` not an `Holiday` object)

use an iterator and iterate into all the `Holidays` present in the `List` and check whether the date matches with inputted date.

Comment: Is that still a binary search?

Comment: No.For doing a binary search you need to sort the array first.